# Add 2th and 3th subcategory to my categorydropdown

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm trying to display my categories and subcategories in drop-down lists. 
I try to make a vehicle selection where the customer has to choose his vehicle first, then the type, then the engine etc.

Until the main category an the first subcategory, I was able to do that.
However, the second and third subcategories are not displayed.

I did not write the part with the Javascript myself, because I am unfortunately still a beginner in Javascript.

Can someone help me and tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Here is my code:

```
<?php
if ( ! class_exists( 'frontendAjaxDropdown' ) ):
    class frontendAjaxDropdown
    {

        function __construct()
        {

            add_shortcode( 'car_conf', array($this, 'init_shortocde') );

            add_action( 'wp_ajax_get_subcat', array($this, 'getSubCat') );
            add_action( 'wp_ajax_get_subsubcat', array($this, 'getSubSubCat') );


            add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_get_subcat', array($this, 'getSubCat') );
            add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_get_subsubcat', array($this, 'getSubSubCat') );

        }

        function init_shortocde()
        {

            wp_dropdown_categories(
                'taxonomy=product_cat&name=main_cat&selected=-1&hierarchical=1&depth=1&hide_empty=0&show_option_none=All Categories'
            );
            ?>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                (function($){
                    $("#main_cat").change(function(){
                        $("#sub_cat").empty();
                        $.ajax({
                            type: "post",
                            url: "<?php echo admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ); ?>",
                            data: { action: 'get_subcat', cat_id: $("#main_cat option:selected").val() },
                            success: function(data) {
                                $("#sub_cat").append(data);
                            }
                        });
                    });
                })(jQuery);

                (function($){
                    $("#sub_cat").change(function(){
                        $("#subsub_cat").empty();
                        $.ajax({
                            type: "post",
                            url: "<?php echo admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ); ?>",
                            data: { action: 'get_subsubcat', cat_id: $("#sub_cat option:selected").val() },
                            success: function(data) {
                                $("#subsub_cat").append(data);
                            }
                        });
                    });
                })(jQuery);
            </script>

            <div id="sub_cat"></div>
            <div id="subsub_cat"></div>

            <?php
        }


        function getSubCat()
        {
            wp_dropdown_categories(
                "taxonomy=product_cat&name=sub_cat&selected=-1&hierarchical=1&depth=1&hide_empty=0&child_of={$_POST['cat_id']}"
            );
            die();
        }

        function getSubSubCat()
        {
            wp_dropdown_categories(
                "taxonomy=product_cat&name=subsub_cat&selected=-1&hierarchical=1&depth=1&hide_empty=0&child_of={$_POST['cat_id']}"
            );
            die();
        }
    }
endif;
new frontendAjaxDropdown();
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you run through any steps for debugging?

Have you tried inspecting your document and seeing if the subcategories show up at all?

I just did a google, and I believe WP has this functionality wrapped in a function:

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_list_categories/

And this might be what you want

Here's two other links which might help

https://www.sitepoint.com/mastering-wordpress-categories-api/
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=n1ZhJ_rIHjQ

Here's a stackoverflow question that seems similar to the one you asked

https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/163372/how-to-get-woocommerce-product-category-link-by-id

In your specific case it seems like you're getting the category ID, but it doesn't seem like you're getting the category name

```
taxonomy=product_cat&name=subsub_cat
```

I am unsure if this is what you were going for. Perhaps you want to add

```
cat_name: $("#main_cat option:selected").val()
```

to your post?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I found my mistake. 
In the script for the third dropdown I had written getsubsubcat instead of getsubcat.